# Python Regex issue translating file system name to exponent

Tags: python, regex

I'm running the following arguments to a script. However my regex is also translating the file systems with numbers in them. I'm not sure were the issue is here:

```
testscript --app-fs=/app=1g,/usr/local2=10g
```

Manual Testing.

```py
import re
appfs = '/app=1024g,/usr/local2=10g'
appfsstr = str(re.sub(r'[\d][Gg]', lambda x: re.sub('[Gg]', '', x.group(0)), re.sub(r'[\d]{1,3}', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) * 1024), appfs)))
print (appfsstr)
```

```
/app=1044484096,/usr/local2048=10444840960
```

Desired output:

```
/app=1048576,/usr/local2=10240
```

Comment: Sorry, but maybe all you need is `re.sub(r'(\d+)[Gg]\b', lambda x: str(int(x.group(1)) * 1024), appfs)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(\d+)[Gg]\b', lambda x: str(int(x.group(1)) * 1024), appfs)
```

The regex matches:

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `[Gg]` - `G` or `g`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The `lambda x: str(int(x.group(1)) * 1024)` replacement takes the match data object (`x`), gets the Group 1 value (`x.group(1)`), casts the string value to an *int*, then multiplies it by `1024` and casts the result back to a string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eAoP7J):

```py
import re
appfs = '/app=1024g,/usr/local2=10g'
print( re.sub(r'(\d+)[Gg]\b', lambda x: str(int(x.group(1)) * 1024), appfs) )
# => /app=1048576,/usr/local2=10240
```